# Python / Tensorflow - Input to reshape is a tensor with 7849215 values, but the requested shape has 7839216

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I'm attempting to create an AI using the MNIST dataset, and all is going well, but I continuously get the same reshape error. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.read_csv('mnist_train_final.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('mnist_test_final.csv')
training_data = pd.read_csv('mnist_train_final.csv')

y = train['label']
train = train.drop(['label'],axis =1)
print(train)

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(train)

s = tf.shape(X)

y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
Xtest =tf.convert_to_tensor(test)
w = tf.shape(Xtest)
print(s)
print(w)

X = tf.reshape(X,(s[0],28,28,1))
Xtest = tf.reshape(Xtest,(w[0],28,28,1))
```

After I run this, I get a reshape error that I'm unsure how to fix:

````
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-86da6dc634d6> in <module>
      1 X = tf.reshape(X,(s[0],28,28,1))
----> 2 Xtest = tf.reshape(Xtest,(w[0],28,28,1))

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 7849215 values, but the requested shape has 7839216 [Op:Reshape]```

Any input on potential fixes is appreciated !
````

Comment: Have you tried removing the label from Xtest as well?
`y_test = test['label']; test = test.drop(['label'],axis =1)`

Answer (score 0):

Well lets start solving this problem by it is error:

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 7849215 values, but the requested shape has 7839216 [Op:Reshape]``
```

As you can see it tells you, that tensor that you current have has  7849215 values. And you are trying to reshape that, by packets of 28. If you come up with a calculator, you are going to notice. If you divide 7849215/28, you get a decimal number which means you have yourself remainder values. Which mean 28 cant fully divide the given tensor into rounded packets (All 28 values being filled).

That means what you need to do is reshape your tensor. By something that is a divisible of 7849215. A good example is the number five. So just change this line to.

```
tf.reshape(Xtest,(w[0],5,5,1))
```